# NSWindow opens but buttons doesn't work and I cannot create IBOutlets

Tags: cocoa, swift4

I have the following `NSWindowController`:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

extension NSImage.Name {

    static let skyflokLogo = NSImage.Name("skyflokLogo")

}
class LoginWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func cancelLogin(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("Jones")
    }
    @IBAction func confirmLogin(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("lol")
    }
}
```

and I open the window like this:

```
   static func loadLoginWindow() -> NSWindowController {
        let win = LoginWindowController(windowNibName: NSNib.Name("LoginWindow"))
        win.showWindow(self)
        return win
    }
```

And store it in the AppDelegate class:

```
@IBAction func loginFunction(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    print("TEST")
    testCtrl = UIHelpers.loadLoginWindow()
}
```

And components the window contains can be seen here:

[image]

My problem is that the window opens as it is supposed to, but my `IBAction` functions does not work and I cannot create `IBOutlet`s by control dragging from the window. Can someone direct me to documentation or help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hold your LoginWindow (I personally recommend to append "Controller" to the class name) instance somewhere. Otherwise, the instance disappears as soon as `loadLoginWindow()` ended, and therefore IBActions cannot be performed.

Comment: and the no IBoutlets part ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that since there is not enough information to clarify it. At least, you can write IBOutlet directly in code.

Comment: I just added some information to the post, and what information do you need

Comment: Have you set the LoginWindowController to File's Owner in the xib?

Comment: So ehhh how to do that... I am new to UI programming in swift

Comment: Thanks for your helped fixed

Comment:  Good to hear.